# Error while executing adb shell command

Tags: shell, quoting, adb

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.test.app --es command "STOP" --es filename "sample 1.01.49 7-09-1380(01).apk"
```

I am trying to broadcast intent using the above `adb` command, where sample `1.01.49 7-09-1380(01).apk` is the file that I would like to broadcast, but I am getting the following error:

```
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected
```

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The command is executed by a shell on Android, so two shells are involved: the local shell that you're typing it in, and the shell on Android that `adb shell` invokes. Therefore you need to quote special characters twice if they need to pass through both shells.

It would be less misleading to write the command as

```
adb shell 'am broadcast -a com.test.app --es command STOP --es filename sample 1.01.49 7-09-1380(01).apk'
```

This causes the following shell command to be executed on Android:

```
am broadcast -a com.test.app --es command STOP --es filename sample 1.01.49 7-09-1380(01).apk
```

But you actually want to execute something like

```
am broadcast -a com.test.app --es command STOP --es filename "sample 1.01.49 7-09-1380(01).apk"
```

Therefore you need the local command to be something like

```
adb shell 'am broadcast -a com.test.app --es command STOP --es filename "sample 1.01.49 7-09-1380(01).apk"'
```